# asp.net mvc and FileName from WebImage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I tried to get filename from uploaded file with WebImage like so:

```
var imageName = new WebImage(file.InputStream).FileName;
```

but FileName property always return null

maybe im missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking through the source of the constructor you are using with Reflector and there is no place they set the file name.

But you can probably get the file name using

```
var fileName = Request.Files[0].FileName;
```

Its only this constructor that set the file name property:

```
public WebImage(string filePath) 
   : this(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current), filePath) {}
```

and of course the private one it uses.

Comment: Request.Files[0].FileName will get full url to he file from my local disk: c:\images\image.jpg

Answer (score 2):

To get the filename of the Uploaded file, you can get the image from the request and then call this function on it.

```
var imageName = new WebImage(file.InputStream).FileName;
```

..would be

```
var image = WebImage.GetImageFromRequest().FileName;
```

This is the property for the image that was uploaded in the Request.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `FileName` property gets set only if you use the `WebImage(String filename)` constructor.  You should be able to get the file name from `file` object. Other properties such as `Height`, `Width`, etc should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `new WebImage(file.InputStream)`, you're creating a `WebImage` object from a raw stream.
You never pass it anything with a name, so the `FileName` property is `null`.

You should use the `file.FileName` property from the `HttpPostedFile` object.